# How to maintain user data in state without prefetching the user in every request

Tags: cookies, next.js, react-redux, strapi

I am creating a web app with **Nextjs**, **Strapi CMS** and **Redux**  with **Cookies**. But I have to check if token has not expire on every request and if it has expired I set **isAuthenticated** to false.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        
        if (isAuthenticated) {
               dispatch(fetchUserDetails()); 
        }
    }, [isAuthenticated]);
```

But isAuthenticated is only for Login and logout. What I want to know is, how to remove the user from the state when the token expires. Should I set a date to logout the user from when the user logged in.

And if so, How schedule a date to logout user when token expires with nexjs and strapi cms or is advisable to check if the token is still active?

Comment: Hi, you have to do it via middleware. If I have time tommo will write you a guide, but gonna need your user slice

Comment: He thanks but I'm still using the Reducer not the slice feature

Comment: In any case you have to do a thunk or middleware and setTimeout inside, and then dispatch…

Comment: can you please me some basic code to get the idea. just anything basic will do and I can take it from there. Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you actually manually need to logout user if token expired, since if you try to access protected strapi route with an incorrect token you would recive 403, so basically you could dispatch logout from any action, just by knowing that it's recived 403.

About dispatching action on "Date", i've would not use the word Date here, since the problem is that server has it's own clock timezone and so on and client also would have own clock and timzeone. And general rule dealing with that is to avoid all cost...

So about the redux part of quetstion, i have't done any reducer/action creators since a year for sure, in modern redux toolkit pseudo code would look something like that (note that timer code is more a concept, just wrote it out of my head):

```
let timer;
const delay = 5000; 

const setTimer = (fn: () => void) => {
   if (typeof timer !== 'undefined') {
      return timer;
   }
   timer = setTimeout(() => fn(), delay);
   return timer;   
}

const clearTimer = () => {
   if (typeof timer !== 'undefined') {
      return clearTimeout(timer);
   }
}

export const timerMiddleware: Middleware = (store) => {
    return (next) => (action) => {
        if (action.type === someSortOfLoginActionType) {
             setTimer(() => store.dispatch(logoutAction());
        }
        if (action.type === someSortOfLogoutActionType) {
             clearTimer();
        }
        // prolly you needs some sort of reset timer
        // but i guess the proper place to handle is 
        // in setTimer function, so it resets if timer
        // already set

        return next(action);
    }
}
```

and a createStore part:

```
export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: { ... }
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware(..).concat(timerMiddleware)
})
```

P.s. not sure it applies to your case, hower this is something i can purpose from description...

Hope that helps!